# Use of hredis vs NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, redis

I'm working on a game engine in objective-c where we want entities to have on-the-fly customization of attributes for each entity. Initially, we were thinking of using NSDictionary, but are also aware of Redis' Objective-C port.

My question is that we will have any performance gains using Redis over NSDictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis is a persistence solution.  NSDictionary is an in-memory key-value store with specific restrictions on keys and values.

The two are focused on solving different problems.

If you reframe the question on persistency of object graphs, then the answer is "Core Data" unless there is some specific, most likely cross platform, need to use something else.

Comment: Entities need only be persisted in memory, while the game is being played. There might be a chance that we want to save the game in future, but it should not affect run-time performance. Hence, CoreData may not be so suitable. Redis is described as a key-value store that persists in memory with options to be written to disk, other nodes, etc. We are concerned about performance.

Comment: Go with NSDictionary to start, for simplicity's sake.  If there is a performance problem, measure and address it.  Unless you have an exceptional situation, you'd be hard pressed to architect something where NSDictionary is going to be the performance bottleneck (certainly, it can be done -- but the problem is at a higher level, almost always).

Comment: I don't have any concrete data (never having used Redis), but if you frame the question this way: "Which would you expect to perform better, the native key-value mechanism used by all Apple's frameworks, or an Objective-C client talking to a general purpose key-value database server?", I know where I would place my bets.

Comment: "more moving parts == more parts to fail" :)

Comment: @david it acts as a server, but you can start it locally. Nonetheless, I will stick with NSDictionary for now. Will accept this as the answer.

Comment: Even if you start it locally, it's still (if I'm understanding correctly) a separate "server" process, so you'll have inter-process communication overhead to contend with.